# PostgreSQL insert into too many referenced table

Tags: postgresql, optimization

I have a simple table with a primary key ID and other columns that are not so interesting. The data there is not so much, like several thousands records. However there too many constraints on this table. I mean it is referenced by other tables (more than 200) with foreign key to the ID column. And every time I tried to insert something into it, it checks all the constraints and takes around 2-3 secs for every insert to complete. There are btree indexes on all tables, so the query planner uses index scans as well as sequential ones.

My question is there any option or something that I can apply in order to speed up these inserts. I tried to disable the sequential scans and use index scans only, but this didn't help. The partitioning wouldn't be helpful as well, I think. So please advise.

The version of psql is 10.0.

Thank you!

Comment: Could you give the definitions for some of the tables and the fkey constraints involved and also the insert query you perform and the explain analyze output for that query. As I currently understand how your tables look there shouldn't be a problem as the constraints would only need checking on delete or update not on insert.

Comment: Here is the table in question:

Comment: Constraint are different from references..And what's constraint? is it just foreign key or there are check constraint?